# is the requirement of being in a lightly obscured area to gain the benefit of the Nature's Mantle works in a heavily obscured area?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, vision-and-light

I want to make sure I'm not creating a problem by allowing heavily obscured areas to meet the requirement of being in a lightly obscured area for the Nature's Mantle benefit of hiding as a bonus action.
Since it is a more obscured area I intended to allow it but I'm not sure if I should since it is not explicitly written.

thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### RAW, no, you cannot use the bonus action hide when heavily obscured, but it probably isn't a problem to allow it.

Rules-as-written, the mantle only allows you to bonus action hide when lightly obscured, and lightly obscured is not the same thing as heavily obscured.

But it probably won't break anything to allow this to work. First, *it makes sense that heavily obscured would be a subset of lightly obscured*, even though that relationship is not defined in the rules. Second, it only makes the Nature's Mantle slightly more versatile - this does not seem like a balance breaking improvement to make. As explained below, the mechanical combat benefits of being hidden are already had without taking the hide action when heavily obscured.

#### You don't have to hide if you are heavily obscured, unless you want to be unheard also.

Taking the hide action allows you to be unseen:

> When you take the Hide action, you make a Dexterity (Stealth) check in an attempt to hide, following the rules for hiding. If you succeed, you gain certain benefits, as described in the "Unseen Attackers and Targets" section later in this section.

These benefits are:

> When you attack a target that you can't see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you're guessing the target's location or you're targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn't in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target's location correctly.
>
> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

So hiding lets you be unseen. But if you are in a heavily obscured area, *you are already unseen*:

> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.

So being in an area of heavy obscurity affords you all of the mechanical benefits in combat  of hiding, that is, disadvantage on attack rolls against you, and advantage on attack rolls against targets that can't see you.

If you want to be totally hidden, *you still have to take the hide action*, since heavy obscurity doesn't do anything for sound.

Comment: I was thinking in the context of having a Gloom Stalker in darkness who is invisible for creatures with darkvision which makes it heavily obscured through the invisible condition who would now need to Hide as an action to not disclose his location.  I understand the RAW part of it and agree it is what it is unless I missed something in the rules that includes lightly obscured in heavily obscured. Also  I wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything important that could have made it necessary to leave it to lightly obscured.